# Meaning of equality in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space. What does it mean for two functions $f,g$ to be equal in $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$ ? Does that mean $\|f-g\|_{L^p}=0$ ? Or that $f-g=0 $ $\mu$-a.e ? If the later is the right answer, what is the difference between being equal in $L^p$ and $L^{p+1}$ ? I mean shouldn't the definition depend on $p$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f,g \in L^p$ then $f = g$ in $L^p$ if and only if $f = g$ a.e. which is if and only if $\|f-g\|_{L^p} = 0$.

The definition of being equal in $L^p$ depends on $p$ only in the sense that you require that the functions themselves are in $L^p$ to say that they are equal in $L^p$.

Comment: So which one is regarded as the definition ? In a general normed vector space $B$, two elements $f,g$ are equal if $f-g=0_B$ or if $||f-g||_B=0 $ ?

Comment: Neither of these is the definition. They are however both equivalent to the the statement $f = g$. Recall that $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ as a set is the quotient of $\mathcal{L}^p(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu) := \{f: f \text{ is measurable and } \int |f|^p d\mu < \infty\}$ by the equivalence relation $f \sim g$ iff $f = g$ a.e. This means that $f = g$ in $L^p$ is a statement about equivalence classes and is true if and only if the equivalence classes are equal as sets (where this last thing is the definition of equality).

Comment: I believe there should be a restriction on the $p$. At least $p\geq 1$, when the $||\cdot||$ becomes a norm.

Comment: @MarineGalantin $p \geq 1$ is more restrictive than needed for this question. For $p \in (0,1)$, $\|\cdot\|$ is a quasi-norm whose $p$-th power induces a complete translation invariant metric for which the vector space operations are continuous. Therefore $L^p$ for $p \in (0,1)$ is an F-space so even has some nice enough topological properties (even though these are completely unnecessary for this question)

Answer (score 2):

For a measurable function $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, the condition $\|f\|_{L^p}=0$ does *not* imply that $f\equiv0$. It only implies that $f=0$ almost everywhere. This means that $\|\cdot\|_{L^p}$ *cannot* be used as a norm for measurable functions. However, it also points to the solution: We need to *identify* two functions if they are equal to each other almost everywhere, and consider $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$ as the set consisting of those *equivalence classes*.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between $L^p$ and $L^q$ with $p>q$ is not about functions being equal or not, but in how much two functions are "near" to each other and in whether some sequences of functions converge to any. For example, the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot 1_{[0,n]}(x)$ converges to zero in $L^2$, but is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^1$ (and therefore cannot converge).